# PHP scraping regex get all values between <td></td>

Tags: php, regex, screen-scraping

I have this string

```
$string = '<td > 157,00</td> <td > 157,20</td> <td > 157,10</td> <td > 157,10</td> <td > 156,60</td> <td > 55 611</td>';
```

Where i try to get the values inside each cell in a array.

```
$value_array = preg_split('/ /',$string);
```

How do i write the spreg split to get all these values?

Comment: You could remove all `<td>` and split by `</td>`.

Comment: You might try doing that like [here](https://ideone.com/yochkd).

Comment: A [DOM parser way](https://ideone.com/PienwQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ave a look on below solution:

```
$html = '<td > 157,00</td> <td > 157,20</td> <td > 157,10</td> <td > 157,10</td> <td > 156,60</td> <td > 55 611</td>';

preg_match_all("'<td >(.*?)</td>'si", $html, $matches1);

$required_array = $matches1[1];
print_r($required_array);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  157,00
    [1] =>  157,20
    [2] =>  157,10
    [3] =>  157,10
    [4] =>  156,60
    [5] =>  55 611
)
```